# How to configure Azure logging after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, azure-diagnostics, .net-core-logging

Are upgrading from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to ASP.NET Core 2.2 and following [the official documentation guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Got a problem with writing the new logging configuration in **Startup.cs**. Specifically problems on how to handle the *AzureWebAppDiagnostics*.

The old configuration consisted of the following configuration:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices);
    loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(
        new AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings
        {
            OutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} [{Level}] {RequestId}-{SourceContext}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
    );
}
```

Both the *AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics* and the *AzureAppServicesDiganosticsSettings* is marked as obsolete. The later suggests to use *AzureBlobLoggerOptions* instead. The guide states that the logging config should be moved to something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddLogging(builder => builder
        .AddConsole()
        .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics());
    ...
}
```

However I have no clue on how to properly add the configuration to the ILoggingBuildler AND as an extra bonus, the *AzureBlobLoggerOptions* does no allow for a custom OutputTemplate. The *AddApplicationInsights* is also missing from the ILoggingBuilder.

Any suggestions on how to get this working like it used to be?

Answer (score 3):

In 2.2 I got this working by splitting the configuration between Program.cs and Startup.cs:

Add this to CreateWebHostBuilder in Program.cs:

```
  .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
        logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
    })
```

Add this to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
{
options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
});
```

This was enough for me to start seeing messages in the Azure App Service log; you need the Nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppService` and corresponding using statements also:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices;
```

Answer (score 2):

Insights is a bit slow to the party. There is a new package with support for the logging builder eg

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.9.0-beta3" />
```

Without that you will need to use the Obsolete way.

Answer (score 1):

The custom OutputTemplate required a dependency on Serilog, which was removed for 2.2, so it's not in the file or blob options classes.

For 2.2 it's recommended to configure logging in Program.cs rather than Startup.cs; here's an example using AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics and the options classes:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics())
        .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
                .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options => {
                    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
                    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
                }).Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options => {
                    options.BlobName = "log.txt";
                }))
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

This requires the NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices` and the following using statements:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

Comment: When I try this, I get 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Configure' and no accessible extension method 'Configure' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I added the package and `using` statements to the answer.